# "Proper" way to access DOM elements outside of Angular 2 template?

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

I have a hunch the correct answer is "you don't--use a service or other solution" but, for the sake of this question, let's say I have to.

My rendered page looks something like this:

```
<div class="somePageHeader">Welcome to my site!</div>
<div my-angular-component>Hi, I'm an angular component!</div>
<div class="somePageFooter">Welcome to my site!</div>
```

In this particular scenario, depending on what's happening inside my-angular-component, I may need to scroll the page. To know where to scroll it, I need to take into account some fixed positioned elements outside of my component (in this example, the site header and footer). Because this component is being shared across multiple projects, I have to retrieve the properties of these elements (specifically, their height) from within my component.

(Disclaimer: I understand that this is probably bad practice to begin with, and that this should all be happening at a higher level than my component, but for the sake of argument, let's say that I just have to get this working and I only have access to the code within my component).

My question: Is there a 'proper' way within angular itself to access the properties of DOM elements outside of my current angular component template?

We *could* use jQuery `$('.somePageHeader')` but--as simple as that is to use--I understand that's a bad habit to lean on jQuery within Angular.

I could just a plain JS `getElementByClassName()` or `document.querySelector()` which (I think?) is fine.

But is there a better, more angular-centric way to go about it? I know about `ViewChild` but from what I understand, that's for accessing DOM elements *within* my template, not outside of it.

Comment: Template reference variable..

Comment: @fastAsTortoise can you elaborate? To clarify, I need to access an element *outside* of my template.

Comment: Using `@ViewChild()` and `template reference` https://alligator.io/angular/viewchild-access-component/

Comment: @AmitChigadani I may be missing the obvious, but...to quote that article "We can access native DOM elements that have a template reference variable". But what if we need to access a DOM element that doesn't have a template reference variable? The issue is that this component is going to live across multiple projects that all have very different DOM structures. And I only have access (at the moment, at least) to the rendered DOM (ie, I can check classes and IDs, for the most part)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `@ViewChild` query.

You can use them to grab from template both native HTML elements (by their class selectors, ids, or via `#templateVariable` references), but also whole components by using their class name:

```
<my-component></my-component>
```

and in controller:

```
@ViewChild(MyComponentClass) variable: MyComponentClass
```

or even further, if directive uses `exportAs` annotation (like `formGroup` is exported as `ngForm`) then you can assign this to template variable:

```
<input [formGroup]="groupName" #controlRef="ngForm">
```

And reference it in your component via `@ViewChild`:

```
@ViewChild('controlRef') cpomponentVariable;
```

After querying its parent component, It's all yours. But be aware of storing it somewhere like service to access it later on. After this component parent will be dismissed, `onDestory` will be invoked and you will basically access garbage.

I believe that it might be related to some design issues because you usually don't need to pass around whole components/template variables, just their states.

Consider using some event bus system based on a service-oriented subject to listen for changes of state and notify about them when you have access to the component you are interested in.

Comment: Can ViewChild access a DOM element *outside* of the component? For example, if I need to access a DOM element where a) I don't know what angular component is rendering it or b) it doesn't have any known template variables?

Comment: @DA. I'm afraid `ViewChild`, as name suggest can dig up only into current component hierarchical child's tree. So for a) answer is no. For b) each rendered angular component can be identified by it's class name, so basically each one of them will exist in template as template variable with name equal to their class.  I'm a bit curious about your particular use case, because I'm unable to figure how your needs

Comment: The use-case is that I need to scroll the page to a particular point, based on what other DOM elements there are on the page (that are position: fixed, as they take away usable viewport space). At the moment, I only have access to the code within the component that will trigger the need to scroll.